# unable to read csv file in jupyter notebook and following errors coming

Tags: pandas, dataframe

### import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('D:\Tableau\codebasics_files\Weather_data.csv.xlsx')
df
​

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18872\1985582496.py in 
1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 df = pd.read_csv('D:\Tableau\codebasics_files\Weather_data.csv.xlsx')
3 df

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
312
313         return wrapper

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
676     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
677
--> 678     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
679
680

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
573
574     # Create the parser.
--> 575     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
576
577     if chunksize or iterator:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in **init**(self, f, engine, **kwds)
930
931         self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
--> 932         self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
933
934     def close(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in _make_engine(self, f, engine)
1232
1233         try:
-> 1234             return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
1235         except Exception:
1236             if self.handles is not None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py in **init**(self, src, **kwds)
73
74         kwds["dtype"] = ensure_dtype_objs(kwds.get("dtype", None))
---> 75         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
76
77         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 14: invalid start byte

​

i tried some options using youtube but not working

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use XLSX function for load and read the XLSX file inside pandas.

For that you need to use this line of code inside your code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('D:\Tableau\codebasics_files\Weather_data.csv.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the very end of the file extension, you're importing a `.xlsx` file, not a CSV file.

Try opening the file on Excel and export it as a CSV. You need to make sure that `.csv` is the last characters of the file.